# Tkinter gif change following mouse click event

Tags: python, tkinter

As i tried to grab window and move it, i have no idea how to change gif images when it needs

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import random
import pystray
from pystray import Menu
from pystray import MenuItem as item
from PIL import Image
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint
import os

lastClickX = 0
lastClickY = 0

window = tk.Tk()
impath = '.\\motions\\' #motions\idle.gif
win_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
win_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

def SaveLastClickPos(event):
    global lastClickX, lastClickY
    lastClickX = event.x
    lastClickY = event.y


def Dragging(event):
    x, y = event.x - lastClickX + window.winfo_x(), event.y - lastClickY + window.winfo_y()
    window.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x , y))
    print("position : " , x, y)


idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'idle.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(5)]#idle gif
idle_to_sleep = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'idle_to_sleep.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#idle to sleep gif
sleep = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'sleep.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(3)]#sleep gif
sleep_to_idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'sleep_to_idle.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#sleep to idle gif
walk_positive = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'walking_positive_remake.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#walk to left gif
walk_negative = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'walking_negative_remake.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#walk to right gif
grab_by_mouse = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'grab_by_mouse.gif', format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(2)] #grabed by mouse


window.config(highlightbackground='black')
label = tk.Label(window,bd=0,bg='black')
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
canbas= tk.Canvas(window, width=win_width, height=win_height, bg = 'black')
label.pack()
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.attributes('-topmost', True)
window.geometry("200x200+500+300")
window.bind('<Button-1>', SaveLastClickPos)
window.bind('<B1-Motion>', Dragging)
window.mainloop()
```

[[[[[[[these are the gif image i was use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FHX7.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgVJq.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Cer.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4LOq.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIIlU.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c61YF.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Uxi.gif)]

I was tried to use after() to make gif works. then GIF looks like they are teleporting the position. how to and where to put GIF works? each of them in BUtton-1, B1-Motion? or make it separatedly?

exept mouse click event

```
import pyautogui
import random
import tkinter as tk
import pystray
from pystray import Menu
from pystray import MenuItem as item
from PIL import Image
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint
import os

#변수설정
check = 1 #행동변수
cycle = 0 #frame 체크
x = 0
y = 0
click_cocunt = 0
event_number = random.randrange(1, 3, 1)
idle_num =[1,2,3,4]
sleep_num = [10,11,12,13,15]
walk_left = [6,7]
walk_right = [8,9]
grab_num = [16]

#윈도우 설정
window = tk.Tk()
impath = '.\\motions\\' #motions\idle.gif
window.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
win_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
win_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
app_width = 100
app_height = 100

center_width = (win_width / 2) - (app_width / 2 )
center_height = (win_height / 2 ) - (app_height / 2)

monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0)))
monitor_area = monitor_info.get("Monitor")
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
task_area = monitor_area[3] - work_area[3]
print("The taskbat height is {}.".format(task_area))#tack bar 위치

print("모니터 사이즈 : ",win_width, win_height)
print("모니터 중심점 : ", int(center_height), int(center_width))
window.resizable(False, False)
window.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(center_width)}+{int(win_height - task_area - app_height)}")# 윈도우 크기100x100 이고 위치 모니터 정 중앙 이 아니라 taskbar 위




#투명화
window.config(highlightbackground='black')
label = tk.Label(window,bd=0,bg='black')
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
canbas= tk.Canvas(window, width=win_width, height=win_height, bg = 'black')
label.pack()


#아이콘 트레이 행동

def action_test():
    print("HI")

def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.visible = False
    icon.stop()
    window.configure(bg='white')
    window.quit()#확인
    print("종료합니다.")

def size_character():
   app_width#아직 하는중

def show_window(icon, item):
    window.after(0, window.deiconify)

def size_up(icon, item):
   print('size up')

def size_down(icon, item):
   print('size down')

def new_window():
   global new
   new = window.Toplevel()#오류

def Add_character(icon, item):
   print('add character')
   new_window()

def Reduce_character(icon, item):
   print('reduce_character')

def reset_position(icon, item):
   x = 0
   window.after(100, x)

def set_position_left():
   x =- 100
   window.after(100, x)

def set_position_right(x):
   x =- 100
   print("right")
   return x

def withdraw_window():
    window.withdraw()

def remove_character():
    window.iconify()

def position_by_mouse():
   x, y = window.winfo_pointerx(), window.winfo_pointery()
   return x, y

def click_detect():
    window.bind("<Button-1>", count)

def count(event):
    if event.num == 1:
        window.after(1, update, cycle, check,  x, y, 1)



#gif 파일 불러오기
idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'idle.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(5)]#idle gif
idle_to_sleep = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'idle_to_sleep.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#idle to sleep gif
sleep = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'sleep.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(3)]#sleep gif
sleep_to_idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'sleep_to_idle.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#sleep to idle gif
walk_positive = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'walking_positive_remake.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#walk to left gif
walk_negative = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'walking_negative_remake.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(8)]#walk to right gif
grab_by_mouse = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath+'grab_by_mouse.gif', format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(2)] #grabed by mouse


#이미지 불러오기 테스트

def gif_work(cycle,frames,event_number,first_num,last_num):
 if cycle < len(frames) -1:
  cycle+=1
 else:
  cycle = 0
  event_number = random.randrange(first_num,last_num+1,1)
 return cycle,event_number


def event(cycle,check,event_number,x,y,click_count):
    if event_number in grab_num:
        check = 6
        window.after(50, update,cycle, check, event_number,x, y) #mouse grab action = 16
    if event_number in idle_num:
        check = 0
        #print('idle')
        window.after(400,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y) #no. 1,2,3,4 = idle
    elif event_number == 5:
        check = 1
        #print('from idle to sleep')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y) #no. 5 = idle to sleep
    elif event_number in walk_left:
        check = 4
        #print('walking towards left')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y)#no. 6,7 = walk towards left
    elif event_number in walk_right:
        check = 5
        #print('walking towards right')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y)#no 8,9 = walk towards right
    elif event_number in sleep_num:
        check  = 2
        #print('sleep')
        window.after(1000,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y)#no. 10,11,12,13,15 = sleep
    elif event_number == 14:
        check = 3
        #print('from sleep to idle')
        window.after(100,update,cycle,check,event_number,x, y)#no. 15 = sleep to idle


def update(cycle,check,event_number,x,y,click_count):
 if click_cocunt == 1:
    check = 6
 #idle
 if check ==0:
  frame = idle[cycle]
  cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,idle,event_number,1,9)  
 #idle to sleep
 elif check ==1:
  frame = idle_to_sleep[cycle]
  cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,idle_to_sleep,event_number,10,10)
#sleep
 elif check == 2:
  frame = sleep[cycle]
  cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,sleep,event_number,10,15)
#sleep to idle
 elif check ==3:
  frame = sleep_to_idle[cycle]
  cycle ,event_number = gif_work(cycle,sleep_to_idle,event_number,1,1)
#walk toward left
 elif check == 4:
  frame = walk_positive[cycle]
  cycle , event_number = gif_work(cycle,walk_positive,event_number,1,9)
  x -= 3
#walk towards right
 elif check == 5:
  frame = walk_negative[cycle]
  cycle , event_number = gif_work(cycle,walk_negative,event_number,1,9)
  x -= -3
 
 elif check == 6:
    frame = grab_by_mouse[cycle]
    cycle , event_number = gif_work(cycle, grab_by_mouse, event_number, 1, 9) #이거 이미지 프레임 단위
    x, y = position_by_mouse()


 window.geometry(f"{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(center_width)+int(x)}+{int(win_height - task_area - app_height)+int(y)}")# 윈도우 크기100x100 이고 위치 모니터 정 중앙 이 아니라 taskbar 위
 label.configure(image=frame)
 window.after(1,event,cycle,check,event_number,x,y,click_cocunt)

#아이콘 트레이 몸체
image_path = Image.open(impath + 'icon-modified.png')
menu = ( 
         item('TEST', action_test),
         item('Quit', quit_window), 
         item('size', Menu(item('size up', size_up), item('size down', size_down))),
         item('Cat Num', Menu(item('Add', Add_character), item('Reduce', Reduce_character))),
         #item('set position_test', Menu(item('reset', reset_position), item('left', set_position_left), item('right', set_position_right))),
        )
icon = pystray.Icon("PET", image_path, "PET_VIEW", menu)

#메인 루프
icon.run_detached()
window.after(10, update, cycle, check, event_number, x, y, click_cocunt)
window.configure(bg = 'black')
window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', withdraw_window)
window.mainloop()
```

was this